# PhoneGap same origin policy and iframes

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, cordova, same-origin-policy

I already know that is possible to make HTTP requests to any domain using phonegap as long as you whitelist it before.

i have a site, which i'm trying to embed in a Phonegap app as an iframe, the parent will have some interactions with phonegap, and will try to modify the iframe content.

is this possible to achieve without modifying the source of my site?

Comment: It wud be gt8 if u post a code

Comment: @VickyGonsalves a code?

Comment: Yes code of what exactly u want to achieve

Comment: This is a question regarding a concept, not a bug in an specific implementation...